# How to pass initial data from url to form foreign key field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm using ModelForm. I know how to pass initial data like:
"domain.com/?field=value"
if field is CharField or somethink like that, but how to pass initial data if field is ForeignKey?
"domain.com/?field__foreign=value" ;) not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you put after the `?` in your URL aren't fields, they are optional parameters. You can then use them in your views and threat them as fields if you want.

Example : `domain.com/?field=myValue`

```
def yourView(request, field=""): #The field has an ampty string as default if not provided in the URL
  #Now we will retrieve the objects where the field "yourField" has the value given in the url (or empty string if none)
  #In the case of this example, field = myValue
  yourObjects = yourModel.filter(yourField = field)
  #Do anything else you want to do in your view
```